# Short story, aliens have conquered, resistance underground with computers etc, tunnel dug to spaceport

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I think this was a short story (unless it was just the start of a book I didn't finish) which I read fairly recently (say 1990-2005). Despite this, I'm not confident that I didn't conflate two stories.

Aliens have conquered Earth and are in (almost) complete control. Humans have been forced back to a less technical lifestyle, possibly because the alien's have weapons that attack fast moving metal, hence horses and wood in use.

There is a resistance movement underground. Specifically, unlike several other stories, they still have access to technology and understand it.

Over a period of years, a tunnel has been extended out to the alien spaceport and a plan is in motion to hide a group of humans aboard an alien ship and spread to other world(s). This tunnel was dug only in tiny spurts when the noise of a ship's launch would cover it. In particular, my memory was that it was computers controlling the digging which was why it was so slow, but still undetected.

Not "The Men in the Walls" by Tenn, or "Tumithak of the Corridors" by Tanner. In both of these the human technology is a forgotten rumour.

I don't think it's "Way of the Pilgrim" by Dickson as that doesn't have anything underground.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your description matches "Footfall" by Niven & Pournelle; however they don't get into an alien ship - rather, they blow a series of nukes under a substantial piece of earth to get launched into space, threatening the aliens' mothership.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I also don't think this matches the "aliens are in complete control" element either, considering that Earth's governments are actively fighting the Fithp.

Comment: Don't remember any tunnel in Footfall.

Comment: No, I enjoyed "Footfall" (love that Orion drive) but the story I remember was a much more complete alien victory. In Footfall, the Fithp only took over a small area of Earth.